# AspxPageControl dynamically Added Pages in Single Usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am creating a dynamic tab with AspxPagecontrol. I have one `UserControl` page. I'm loading dynamically based on Id. However, when I try to load my `UserControl` page with a different Id, the other page appears empty.

I would be glad if you help.
Good work.

```
   protected void btnNewTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Id = (((ASPxButton)sender).CommandArgument);

        PageList.Add(Id);
        if (Session["PageList"] == null)
        {
            Session.Add("PageList", PageList);
            TabAdd(Id);
        }
        else
        {
            if (((List<string>)Session["PageList"]).Contains(Id))
            {
                foreach (TabPage tab in ASPxPageControl1.TabPages)
                {
                    if (tab.Name == "Page" + Id)
                    {
                        ASPxPageControl1.ActiveTabIndex = tab.Index;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ((List<string>)Session["PageList"]).Add(Id);
                TabAdd(Id);
            }
        }
    }

    void TabAdd(string Id)
    {
        TabPage newPage = new TabPage("Page" + Id, "Page" + Id);
        ASPxPageControl1.TabPages.Add(newPage);

        for (int i = 0; i < ASPxPageControl1.TabPages.Count; i++)
        {
            IssuesDetails cc = (IssuesDetails)Page.LoadControl("~/IssuesDetails.ascx");
            cc.matchID = Id;
            cc.ID = Id;
            ASPxPageControl1.TabPages[ASPxPageControl1.TabPages.Count - 1].Controls.Add(cc);
        }

        ASPxPageControl1.ActiveTabIndex = ASPxPageControl1.TabPages.Count - 1;
    }


 <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnYeniTab" runat="server"  CommandArgument="1" Text="Yeni Tab1" OnClick="btnNewTab_Click"></dx:ASPxButton>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnYeniTab2" runat="server" CommandArgument="2" Text="Yeni Tab2" OnClick="btnNewTab_Click"></dx:ASPxButton>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnYeniTab3" runat="server" CommandArgument="3" Text="Yeni Tab3" OnClick="btnNewTab_Click"></dx:ASPxButton>

                <dx:ASPxPageControl ID="ASPxPageControl1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ActiveTabIndex="1" Height="400px" 
                    Width="100%"  EnableCallBacks="true">
                    <TabPages  >
                        <dx:TabPage Name="AnaTab">
                            <ContentCollection >
                                <dx:ContentControl runat="server">
                                </dx:ContentControl>
                            </ContentCollection>
                        </dx:TabPage>
                    </TabPages>
                </dx:ASPxPageControl>
```